# Other-version Spark in Hortonworks HDP doesn't work

Tags: apache-spark, hortonworks-data-platform

[I put a pre-build spark1.4 package into HDP2.4,but example SparkPi doesn't work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkitT.png)

[spark-shell will get no message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfjq1.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the spark-assembly jar.
When you download spark and unpack it, you have the assembly jar in path `\spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6\lib\spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar`
In your case you need to check if spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar exists in the location  `/usr/hdp/2.4.0.0-169/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib`.